# The editor has encountered an unexpected error wordpress

Tags: editor, recovery, attempto

[Attempt Recovery, Copy Post Text and Copy Error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdqQw.png)
Attempt Recovery, Copy Post Text and Copy Error.

this option will comes after update the WordPress, during open the page or post this above issue will comes

Roll back the data again update but still same issue comes, after that I have try to one by one uninstall the plugin but still issue present.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Your Plugins section
2. Add new plugin classic editor.
3. After install , than activate the plugin.